# Получение координат места пользователя мобильного телефона, посредством использование сайта

Tags: javascript, api

уважаемые разработчики! Меня интересует создание функции, при клике на  которую, она смогла бы считать координаты места данного пользователя. Естественно с его разрешения. Я пока не знаю, будет ли это мобильное приложение или сайт. Повлияет ли мой выбор на конечный результат? А добиваюсь я получение координат, с максимальной погрешностью 3-4 метра. 
Я вас очень прошу ответить, возможно ли это и если возможно, посоветуйте пожалуйста, с чего начать. В каком направлении двигаться? И можно ли использовать для этой задачи, любые платформы карт(Google, Яндекс, OpenStreetMap, Leaflet)?
P.S. Функция будет доступна исключительно при открытии сайта с мобильного устройства!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

Comment: Погрешность гражданского GPS может достигать в городе 50 метров. Это если не повезет.

Comment: Я хотел сделать  функцию-оповещения, чтобы пользователь мог отправлять фотографии проблемных зон, связанных с мусором в парках, как пример. Но если погрешность равна 50 метров, то как это сделать? Всё получается бесполезно?

Comment: Можно определять положение, но давать пользователю возможность это положение подкорректировать.

Comment: Или модератору... Я сейчас нашёл один сервис: https://check-location.ru/ который определяет местоположение по мобильному телефону(тоже можно) Вы не можете сказать, как он это делает? Какие технологии  использовали разработчики, для создания данного сервиса?

Comment: Технологии мошеннического выманивания денег с доверчивых людей, вестимо.

Comment: Возможно вы правы!